# Strict weak ordering operator in C++

Tags: c++

I'm writing genetic algorithm for TPS. I've got class Chromosome that is derived from std::vector and has fitness as a member. I would like to sort population of chromosomes. IMO my operator< is 'strict weak ordering' relation. However, MVS thinks otherwise. Here is the code of operator:

```
bool Chromosome::operator<(const Chromosome & rhs) const
{
    const Chromosome& lhs = *this;
    if (lhs.fitness < rhs.fitness)
        return true;
    else
    {

        unsigned int size = lhs.size();
        unsigned int zeroCityIndexlhs = std::find(lhs.begin(), lhs.end(), 0) - lhs.begin();
        unsigned int zeroCityIndexrhs = std::find(rhs.begin(), rhs.end(), 0) - rhs.begin();
        for (unsigned int i = 1; i < size; i++)
        {
            if (lhs[(zeroCityIndexlhs + i) % size] < rhs[(zeroCityIndexrhs + i) % size])
                return true;
            else if (lhs[(zeroCityIndexlhs + i) % size] == rhs[(zeroCityIndexrhs + i) % size])
                continue;
            else
                return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Chromosome A is less than chromosome B, when it has smaller fitness, or the same fitness and a road starting from city 0 is lexicographically lesser than road in B. Program compiles but when it comes to sorting (using std::sort()), runtime error shows up with "Debug Assertion Failed!... invalid comparator".

Comment: And if you took two certain chromosomes for which `assert failed` does `operator<(a, b) == operator<(b, a)`?

Comment: `std::vector` of what??  In other words, are you sure `operator<` on the contained objects is sound.

Comment: Btw you do not need `else` when you have return statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing the other side of the fitness check:

```
bool Chromosome::operator<(const Chromosome & rhs) const
{
    const Chromosome& lhs = *this;
    if (lhs.fitness < rhs.fitness)
        return true;
    else if (rhs.fitness < lhs.fitness)
        return false; // <== this!
```

Otherwise, if `lhs.fitness > rhs.fitness`, you're checking the vectors, when you shouldn't.

Comment: It works, great thanks! Seems like sometimes i have to take a break from coding

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::tuple`:

```
bool Chromosome::operator<(const Chromosome & rhs) const
{
    // Fill in the ... here.
    using base_type = std::vector<...>;

    return std::tie(fitness, static_cast<base_type const&>(*this)) <
        std::tie(rhs.fitness, static_cast<base_type const&>(rhs));
}
```

Side note: inheriting from `std::vector<...>` is pretty horrible. Use a `std::vector<...>` data member and implement the functionality you need as forward functions.

Answer (score 0):

When `rhs.size()<lhs.size()` your comparison function looks seriously wrong. (Not just a bad comparison rule, but undefined behavior as well).

That might be fixed inside your `operator[]` which I don't see.  So I can't be certain of the above.  But since that fits the described symptoms, I am assuming you didn't actually fix it inside `operator[]`

Even for `rhs.size()>lhs.size()` there is something very questionable in your code.  So it seems you are assuming they are the same size.  If so, throw an `assert` in, so code reviewers might believe that.

Comment: Yeah, I assumed that they are same size. I will throw assert there.